# In Cypress, trying to have multiple contexts leads to tests not finishing

Tags: cypress

After years of reviewing answers here, I finally have a question ^^

I'm a new Cypress user and trying to make tests one after another, but doing so make the first context to finish before all its tests (line 29).

Please find code below :

```
    describe('Home', () => {

      beforeEach(() => {
        cy.viewport(1920, 1080)
        visit('home')
      })

      context('Content and links', ()=>{

        before(() => {
          getTransloco('market', 'fr').then(res => loco = res);
          cy.clearFirestore();
          cy.importData({
            ...marketWithSellers(market, [seller]),
            ...createStandaloneProducts(products, seller),
          });
        })
      
        it('Contains all data and links', async () => {
          cy.contains(loco.app)
          cy.contains(loco.subtitle)
          get('order').contains(loco.order)
          cy.log('ongoing')
          get('signin').contains(loco.signin)
          get('link-home').should('exist')
          get('link-market').should('exist').should('have.class','disabled')
          get('link-orders').should('exist')
          get('link-profiles').should('not.exist')
          get('link-signin').should('exist')  // <== the test stops here /!\
          get('order').click()
          cy.contains(loco['select-market'])
          get('market_0').should('exist').contains(market.name!)
          cy.get('[aria-roledescription="map"]').should('exist')
          cy.get('[role="button"]').should('exist')
          cy.contains(loco['sellers-list']).scrollIntoView().should('exist')
          get('seller_0').contains(seller.name)
          get('link-about').should('exist')
          get('link-facebook').should('exist')
          get('link-instagram').should('exist')
          get('link-twitch').should('exist')
          cy.contains(loco.contact)
          get('link-contact').should('have.attr', 'href', 'mailto:contact@kampoy.com')
        })

      })

      context('Top nav bar', ()=>{

        before(() => {
          getTransloco('buyer', 'fr').then(res => loco = res);
        })

        it('Nav bar appears after scrolling down', () => {
          get('top-nav').should('not.have.class', 'visible')
          get('link-contact').scrollIntoView()
          get('top-nav').should('have.class', 'visible')
        })
      
        it('Nav bar appears only has home, auth and order links', () => {
          get('top-nav').children().should('have.length', 3)
          get('top-nav link-home').contains(loco['app-name'])
          get('top-nav link-auth').contains(loco.signin)
          get('top-nav link-order').contains(loco.order)
        })

      })

    })
```

The strange part is, if I comment the second context (top nav bar), then all my first context is working fine...

Does anyone understand why ?

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Not sure if this is it or not, but why is that first `it` async? Could you remove that and have the code run without it?

Comment: Hello Agoff :) It was a remnant from some earlier code. Got rid of it, and now it works... Details details ^^
Any way, thanks a bunch mate !